# Shareable content which requires login

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Here is a question which describes what I want to do:

[Facebook "Like" button not "liking" content inside secured folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075189/facebook-like-button-not-liking-content-inside-secured-folder)

In short, I want to have a like button on pages that only authenticated users can visit. The purpose of this is that the link can be shared to facebook but when people click the link inside Facebook they will be redirected to a "You must login to see this" page.

Anyway the way I thought about doing it was to look at the useragent from Facebook and instead of redirecting or allowing the page to be displayed, I would just write a seperate response containing the open graph meta data but none of the actual page HTML.

In my mind at least, this bypasses the problem of useragent spoofing because no HTML will be displayed to them, so they're still not getting access to the content. I'm just not sure how Facebook feels about this, is it "gaming" the system?

Even better, is there another reliable way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I can't think of any other way to do it..  I like this design.

Comment: That's good. Well I've tried it and it works perfectly exactly as I had hoped. The page requires a user to be logged in to view it, if Facebook hits it however it is still able to see the metadata so the page can be liked, and if you're spoofing your user-agent you will only get the metadata. So no objections or illegality here?

Comment: Just discovered that this is called cloaking and is generally not a good idea, but I can't think of any other way to work around this problem.

Comment: You might be able to avoid having to sniff the user agent though.  You can *like* a page called FBLink.html which sends the correct open graph data, then uses script to redirect to the secure page.